# What line of code do I put in my MainActivity to be able to use the new Class?

Tags: java, android

New To Android programming, need some help Please.
Creating my first App.

I Created a new Class and now am trying to use the class can you please me, Dont know what to put in my `MainActivity.java` to use the new class, here is the `MainActivity`, and also the class.

What line of code do I put in my `MainActivity` to be able to use the new Class?
Thank you very much.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Determine whether the current user is an anonymous user
    if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
        // If user is anonymous, send the user to LoginSignupActivity.class
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                LoginSignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        // If current user is NOT anonymous user
        // Get current user data from Parse.com
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            // Send logged in users to Welcome.class
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            // Send user to LoginSignupActivity.class
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    LoginSignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }           
    }

}    
}
```

**Here is the Class:**

```
public class RaceCar extends Activity {

TextView tvHttp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvHttp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.httptest);

    GetData obj = new GetData();
    obj.execute("http://racecar.com");

}

public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String data = null;

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI uri = new URI(params[0]);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stream));           
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
            buffer.append(line + newLine);
        }
        reader.close();

        data = buffer.toString();
        return data;

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (reader !=null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    tvHttp.setText(result);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: did you register it in your manifest?

Comment: You may have to send it an intent to the new class.

Comment: <activity android:name=".racecar" >
        </activity>

Comment: can you tell me how, what code to write in the MainActivity to do so

Comment: check the tutorial I linked to. I can't write something better than that. If you run into a code issue, post it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the `RaceCar` Activity class from `MainActivity` you have to open it with an `Intent` like you have done for `Welcome.class` and `LoginSignupActivity.class`.

For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RaceCar.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You must also include this `RaceCar.class` Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside the Application section like so:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.app.RaceCar"
    android:label="RaceCar">
       <!-- Make sure this is the full path to your Activity class -->
</activity>
```

It should look similar to your definition for `MainActivity` in there.

Further reading on Activities can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) (Well worth a thorough read).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent` to make call to `Activity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RaceCar.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Register the new `Activity` in `manifest.xml`.

```
<activity android:name="packageName.RaceCar"    
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: Going to give it a Try Thank you